# ReferenceError: ok is not defined

Tags: html, css, vue.js

i recently learning about `vue`
I have this file `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning Vue Js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"> 
    <button @click="show = !show">Toggle</button>
    <div class="foo" v-show="ok">
        <p>ok</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = new Vue({
    el: "#root",
    data: {
        ok: false
    }
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `ok` is clearly defined in `data`, but `show` is not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: { ok: false }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="root"> 
    <button @click="ok= !ok">Toggle</button>
    <div class="foo" v-show="ok">
        <p>ok</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
<button @click="ok = !ok">Toggle</button>
<div class="foo" v-if="ok">
    <p>ok</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22486055)